# Generic way to read any XML with multiple nested levels into structured tables, to be written to Excel

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, dataset, c#-datatable

I am trying to read XML files generated by a third party application (without an XSD document), containing multiple nested levels.

My objective is to loop over XML data in a structured way, and write to multiple sheets in an Excel file, in order to analyze the data further.

The XML file can have any number of nested levels, and any number of fields in each level. The data type of the field is not mentioned in XML and there is no schema (the schema has to be inferred), but each field data type can be taken as string. If the data type of a field can also be inferred, it is better but I can do without this.

Within the same level, some fields may come in some records, and may not come in other records.
The only nodes to be handled are elements and attributes. There won't be any comments or CDATA section.

The below XML is given only as an example. Actual XML may vary.

Notice that `DocRemarks` is there in 2nd Document, but not in the 1st Document, whereas `DocStatus` is there in 1st Document only. The 2nd Document tag has `IsDraft` attribute. The 2nd Document has `ItemBatch` records under `ItemLine` for the 2nd item, but none of the other items have these records.

```
<Main>
 <Document>
  <CustomerName>ABC</CustomerName>
  <DocDate>01-Jan-2020</DocDate>
  <DocNum>1</DocNum>
  <ItemLine>
   <ItemName>Item1</ItemName>
   <ItemQty>100</ItemQty>
  </ItemLine>
  <ItemLine>
   <ItemName>Item2</ItemName>
   <ItemQty>90</ItemQty>
  </ItemLine>
  <DocStatus>Approved</DocStatus>
 </Document>
 <Document IsDraft="Yes">
  <CustomerName>ABC</CustomerName>
  <DocDate>02-Jan-2020</DocDate>
  <DocNum>2</DocNum>
  <ItemLine>
   <ItemName>Item1</ItemName>
   <ItemQty>100</ItemQty>
  </ItemLine>
  <ItemLine>
   <ItemName>Item2</ItemName>
   <ItemQty>90</ItemQty>
   <ItemBatch>
    <BatchName>B1</BatchName>
    <BatchQty>30</BatchQty>
   </ItemBatch>
   <ItemBatch>
    <BatchName>B2</BatchName>
    <BatchQty>60</BatchQty>
   </ItemBatch>
  </ItemLine>
  <DocRemarks>My Remarks</DocRemarks>
 </Document>
</Main>
```

The final objective is to put all immediate child fields of `Document` in one Excel sheet, all child fields of `ItemLine` in 2nd sheet, all child fields of `ItemBatch` in next sheet, and so on with the ability to relate which child records belong to which parent level, and vice versa.

**What I have tried:**

I have used `DataSet.ReadXml` method, using `InferSchema` parameter.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFileName, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

This generates a DataSet with 3 DataTables: Document, ItemLine and ItemBatch.

**Questions:**

Once the DataSet is loaded, I need to write to Excel in a logical sequence of DataTables.
In this case, the 1st sheet should be `Document`, 2nd sheet should be `ItemLine` and 3rd sheet should be `ItemBatch`. One parent table can have multiple child tables, for example the `Document` can have `ItemLine` as well as `GLLine` tables (not shown in the example XML)

1. How do I figure out that the table named `Document` goes to Sheet 1, `ItemLine` goes to Sheet2, and so on? I cannot hardcode the table names.
2. Within each sheet i.e. for each DataTable, I need to write the columns for Primary Key, Foreign Key at the every beginning before writing out the other columns. For example, for the `Document` table, the DataTable has an auto-generated column `Document_Id`. This should be the 1st column in the Excel sheet.

For the `ItemLine` table, the DataTable has `ItemLine_Id` and `Document_Id` auto-generated columns. In this case, I want these 2 as the 1st 2 columns in the Excel sheet.

Comment: the DataSet method ReadXml create fragmented DataTable that cannot be recombined.  The ReadXml make the first xml tag the table names, the second xml tags the column names and the third xml tags the row data.  Once you get more than the three or have xml attributes the results is a big mess of fragmented tables.

Comment: I just need to know the DataTables in each level of XML so that I can write to Excel in the same order. And for each DataTable, I need to know what are the auto generated column names for Primary Key and Foreign Key.

Comment: As I said it is fragmented and you cannot make any sense of the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should be able to load nested tag into a separate table:

```
public string ReadXMLFile(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var response = "";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();        
    ds.ReadXml((request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result));           
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        //Code Here for Insert or Any Other
    }
    return response;
}
```